# Any library that does printf on a C++ stream?

Tags: c++, stream, printf

Does anyone know a library that implements [`std::printf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf) functionality on standard C++ streams? I'm looking for a manipulator that would allow me to write:

```
std::cout << ns::stream_printf("There are %d cookies in %d jars\n", 
                                num_cookies, num_jars);
```

A reasonable implementation using variable templates (or emulation of them) could even offer dynamic type safety, i.e. an exception on malformed format string, instead of the program crashing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Boost.Format](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/format/doc/format.html) can use a syntax that is very close to `sprintf`.

From the linked tutorial:

```
cout << boost::format("writing %1%,  x=%2% : %3%-th try") % "toto" % 40.23 % 50; 
     // prints "writing toto,  x=40.230 : 50-th try"
```

Comment: It's actually very nicely done, except... The use of `%` for the inserter makes any code using it completely unreadable.  (Python used `%` for a while, but found the same problem, and replaced it with a named function.)

Comment: @jons34yp Of course.  A string is a string, and the code in `boost::format` doesn't know where it came from.

Comment: @JamesKanze:  Exactly why I never actually use Boost.Format, and finally submitted to using streams after years of resistance.

Comment: @JohnDibling I actually implemented a `Format` class before Boost had it (before there was Boost, in fact).  It was overly complicated (because someone challenged me to make it 100% compatible with `printf`), but most of all, I found that it didn't solve any real problems.  I implemented it for the extended placement formatters from X/Open, but every time I needed to support more than one language, I needed more than just changing the order of the inserted values.  It ended up being a solution in search of a problem.

Comment: @JamesKanze: I went through the same exercise years ago as well.  It was rethought and rehashed until finally it ended up being a `StringBuilder` class using streams.  I still use it to this day when I don't have access to one of the nearly infinite libraries where this is implemented already.

Comment: Despite proclaiming near complete compatibility with *printf* (with very rare documented exceptions), Boost::Format is mere a wrapper for built-in stream formatting. So, when you do `std::uint8_t x = UINT8_C(42); std::cout << (boost::format("%" PRIu8) % x).str();` you get a “*” character instead of expected “42”, even though the library declares explicit support for "%c" format specifier for characters. This discrepancy was discussed a decade ago, so it is safe to assume WONTFIXEVER.

Answer (score 0):

The iof at http://sf.net/projects/iof is an alternative to boost. With it you can do the following:

```
cout << iof::fmt("There are %d cookies in %d jars\n") 
     << num_cookies << num_jars;
```

The only difference with printf is that you always use %s since C++ knows the type. You use f, g etc inside the placeholder to format:

```
cout << iof::fmt("The number %.2fs is a float value with 2 decimals") 
     << 3.141592 << endl;
```

You can also do some neat things like

```
cout << iof::fmt("XYZ coords: %8.4fS %s %s\n") 
     << x << y << z;
```

which will "persist" the format across multiple %s placeholders.

You can also get the equivalent of sscanf and such via its input capability, in case you don't need full regexp parsing:

```
float a, b, c;
cin >> iof::fmt("%fs,%fs,%fs") >> a >> b >> c;
```